# Select-statement: different result in direct query and pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I don't get why this is not working.

There are two tables:

```
a)  id  | value    b) id  |  value
    ----------        ------------
    1   |  1          1   | Hello
    2   |  2          2   | Bye
    3   |  1
```

I am doing this query containing a left join:

```
select b.value
from a
left join b on a.value = b.id
where a.id = 2
```

The result is: 'Bye'. Which is correct.

But if I am using the same statement in a package with pl/sql it gets the wrong result:

```
select b.value into word
from a
left join b on a.value = b.id
where a.id = 2 and rownum <= 1
```

The result is: word = 'Hello' which is incorrect.

Comment: why rownum, if query returns only one result?

Comment: From what you show us this seems impossible. This is the same database? No other records in the tables?

Comment: Aramillo: Yes, rownum is not necessary. Without rownum it is returning more than one value which leads to an exception. So I added rownum to get at least the wrong result.

Comment: Thorsten: Yes, it is impossible. At least I don't get the point. But I tried it several times and I don't get what's wrong.

Comment: There is no PL/SQL (=stored procedure) in your question

Comment: Horse: Yes, I didn't write this part. It is in a procedure like: PROCEDURE GET_VALUE
  (
    
  ) AS
    WORD VARCHAR2(6000);
  BEGIN ... END GET_VALUE;

Comment: We don't have your pl/sql, so we have no idea what's happening, but check this [invoker rights](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/dr_ir.htm#DBSEG658)

Answer (score 1):

You get an exception without the `ROWNUM` clause inside your PL/SQL function, whereas you get only one result when running the query directly. That's a clear indicator that your PL/SQL procedure is not using the same tables as your adhoc query.

Please check:

- do you run your adhoc query as the same user that owns the PL/SQL package?
- do you use schema prefixes for your table names in your PL/SQL package?
- is your package using invoker rights (i.e. does it contain `AUTHID CURRENT_USER`)? If yes, why?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, remove "rownum <= 1" condition.
If you really need it, try this:

```
select value
into word
  from (select b.value
        from a
        left join b on a.value = b.id
        where a.id = 2)
where rownum <= 1;
```

To understand better what is going on, try to execute this:

```
with a as (select 1 id, 1 value from dual union all
           select 2, 2 from dual union all
           select 3, 1 from dual),
     b as (select 1 id, 'Hello' value from dual union all
           select 2, 'Bye' from dual)
select a.id aid, a.value avalue, b.id bid, b.value bvalue, rownum
  from a left join b on a.value = b.id;
```

this:

```
with a as (select 1 id, 1 value from dual union all
           select 2, 2 from dual union all
           select 3, 1 from dual),
     b as (select 1 id, 'Hello' value from dual union all
           select 2, 'Bye' from dual)
select a.id aid, a.value avalue, b.id bid, b.value bvalue, rownum
  from a left join b on a.value = b.id
 where a.id = 2;
```

this:

```
with a as (select 1 id, 1 value from dual union all
           select 2, 2 from dual union all
           select 3, 1 from dual),
     b as (select 1 id, 'Hello' value from dual union all
           select 2, 'Bye' from dual)
select a.id aid, a.value avalue, b.id bid, b.value bvalue, rownum
  from a left join b on a.value = b.id
 where rownum = 1;
```

and this:

```
with a as (select 1 id, 1 value from dual union all
           select 2, 2 from dual union all
           select 3, 1 from dual),
     b as (select 1 id, 'Hello' value from dual union all
           select 2, 'Bye' from dual)
select a.id aid, a.value avalue, b.id bid, b.value bvalue, rownum
  from a left join b on a.value = b.id
 where a.id = 2 and rownum = 1;
```

And compare results.
Your problem is not in the difference between SQL and PL/SQL, but in behavior of rownum.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using for binding value=id? its bit of disturbing, nevermind. In addition you have a rownum "constraint" between the condition. So think it over, you are saying to oracle to do a left join on value and id, and in the condition you saying you only need the first row, which means the set will only containing the Hello "related" element